# When is ProcessPacket is getting called in addSyncStanzaListener (smack 4.1.4)

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am trying to receive chat messages in my android chat application which I am developing using smack 4.1.4 library, I am able to send messages but I am not able to receive any message. `ProcessPacket` method below is not getting called. Here is my code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        StanzaFilter filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message.class);
        connection.addSyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
            public void processPacket(Stanza stanza) {
                Message message = (Message) stanza;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = message.getFrom();
                    chatMessage newMsg = new chatMessage(message.getBody(), "in");
                    chatList.add(newMsg);
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                    myadapter = new chatAdapter(actualChatActivity.this, R.layout.single_message, chatList);
                    chatListView.setAdapter(myadapter);
                }
            }
        }, filter);
        return null;
    }
public Void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection)
{
    this.connection=connection;
    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us

        new ReceiveMessageTask().execute();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How could I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

try with `addPacketListener` instead `addSyncStanzaListener`

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
                    connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    messageReceived(
                            StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom()), 
                            message.getBody()
                            );
                }
            }
        }, filter);
```

Comment: would you tell me how can i send & receive msg using this library 4.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following filter:

```
FromMatchesFilter filter = FromMatchesFilter.createBare("id@jabber.org");
m_packet_collector = m_connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
```

Bare vs Full filter:  Bare format ,matches only the "id@jabber.org", while full filter matches "id@jabber.org/resoure".